# Source for this claim: "In high dimensions, all data are multicollinear."

Tags: high-dimensional

In the encyclopedia of statistics article on the curse of dimensionality, one reads:

> Scott and Wand [5] show that high dimensionality increases the
> probability that a data set of fixed size n lies close to some proper
> subspace.

But looking in the referenced paper, I don't see this problem explicitly treated in the paper (the "show" part of the sentence above). In any case, I would have liked to know of other papers that study this.

## Edit:

Intuitively, the LLN applies to the rows $\{x_{ij}\}_{j=1}^p=\pmb x_i\in\mathbb{R}^p$ of my $n\times p,n>p$ data matrix $X$, we have that for any positive number $\epsilon$, $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$,

$$\lim_{p\to\infty}\Pr\!\left(\,|\text{ave}_{j=1}^px_{ij}-\mu_i| > \varepsilon\,\right) = 0.$$

If the rows of $X$ are identically distributed, then $\mu_i=\mu\;\forall i$ so that in this sense the data would be lying closer and closer to an hyperplane. Is this the intuition behind this claim?

1. Scott, D. W. and Wand, M. P. (1991). Feasibility of multivariate density estimates.
   Biometrika, 78, 197–205.

Comment: If X is an n by k data matrix and k is larger than n, then X can have at most rank n.

Comment: yes, but I understand the claim to apply outside of the trivial case $n<=k$ ("*increases* the probability")

Comment: Think of some purely random data $X_{ij}\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$. If $n\gg p$, the covariance matrix will be essentially proportional to the identity matrix, so in the limit of $n/p \to \infty$ all its eigenvalues are positive and equal ("data occupy the whole space"). If $n/p<1$ then there trivially must be some zero eigenvalues. For $n>p$ as $n/p$ decreases and approaches $1$, more and more eigenvalues will be getting very small and approaching zero, i.e. data will get more and more confined to a lower-dimensional subspace.

Comment: I don't know if it's treated in the Scott and Wand paper, but it's certainly *mentioned* in it:  "*The more significant aspect of data analysis in higher dimensions is the tendency of data to fall into manifolds of lower dimension.*"  (p204, Sec 5, 3rd paragraph, 4th sentence)

Comment: @Glen_b: yes I saw this, but is there an argument/intuition for this? I would like to know if mine is correct!

Comment: Oh, okay, it wasn't clear from your question whether you had seen it.

Comment: @amoeba, I think your comment is relevant and clear (more relevant than the currently available answer, IMHO). Perhaps you should turn it into an answer.

Comment: @Richard, thanks; one reason I posted it as a comment is that the question is formulated as asking primarily about references. I don't know any good references, hence cannot answer the main part of the question. User603, if you are more interested in the substantial answers about why this phenomenon is the case than about the references, perhaps you can edit to make this clearer.

Comment: @amoeba: A formal argument (for the last sentence in your answer, which is what I am really interested in here) would of course do just as fine as a reference!

Answer (score 3):

This response is likely *not* the explicit treatment requested. This question 
reminded me of David Scott's comments at the first joint ASA/NSF conference on *Massive Data* when he said, "The only thing massive about massive data is the massive redundancy." In terms of analysis of high dimensional data, his recommendation was to focus on the mode as the best measure of central tendency and he's since published papers on approaches to *mode clustering*. But his views are largely unknown and, for all intents and purposes, lost on today's audience of analysts.

More common is the opposite view about the relation between collinearity and data size. For instance, in Gujarati's widely used textbook on econometrics he describes multicollinearity as a *small* data problem where a theoretical set of predictors "are not linearly related in the population" but can be in the finite data sample at hand. In this view and since *all* data is finite -- even at the petabyte level -- the potential for collinearity rapidly explodes in high dimensions.

Finally and related to this is the intuition driven by the assumption that predictors be *iid*, at least in the theoretical, asymptotic, infinite limit. In the reality of applied analysis, however, data is rarely *iid* and dependence structures -- both linear and nonlinear -- where everything is endogenous and everything is correlated are rife.